# How to configure BASE_PATH in swagger open api?

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I am struggling to find a way to configure the BASE_PATH.

I want to configure the base path server side

I am using open-api-generator to generate subs from a swagger endpoint (asp core web api)

[image]

Is there a way to configure different BASE_PATH.

Answer (score 1):

How you define the base URL is specific to the version of OpenAPI Specification you target.

### Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0

Define a [host](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v2.0.html#swaggerHost) at the root of your document. For [example](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/f8449d1a893cc6a811c6f3d87e88b05761dc5397/examples/v2.0/yaml/petstore.yaml#L7):

```yaml
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Petstore
  license:
    name: MIT
host: petstore.swagger.io
basePath: /v1
schemes:
  - http
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /pets:
    …
```

### OpenAPI 3.x

Define a URL in [servers](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3.html#fixed-fields) at the root of your document. For [example](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/f8449d1a893cc6a811c6f3d87e88b05761dc5397/examples/v3.0/petstore.yaml#L8):

```yaml
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Petstore
  license:
    name: MIT
servers:
  - url: http://petstore.swagger.io/v1
paths:
  /pets:
    …
```

Comment: not sure how to define that in .netcore web api? is there a guide please

Comment: It depends on whatever plugin or extension you're using in your .netcore api to generate the OpenAPI Document. You'll have to look at the documentation of that tool to understand how to configure either host (if your doc is version 2.0) or servers (if your doc is version 3.x).